# What is the origin of the idiom "tight fit" meaning a good joke?

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms, expressions, slang

I've recently been studying etymology and I received a book titled *Flappers 2 Rappers: A Study of American Youth Slang* written by Dr. Thomas Dalzell. Dr. Dalzell's research goes as far back as the 1850s and one of his entries of that decade is "tight fit" meaning a good joke.

According to http://www.etymonline.com/ the word "killing" meaning extremely funny dates even further back to the 1840s. I understand why a killing is something very funny because when one laughs too hard it causes stomach muscle spasms and shortness of breath, almost restricting the lungs from getting air.

I haven't the least notion why a "tight fit" is a good joke. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which dictionary says : Tight fit means a good joke?

Comment: Are you sure that "tight fit" means "good joke" – and not something more along the lines of "especially approproiate joke?" Some jokes are funny because there is an element of truth to them, or an impersonator might say something you could easily imagine being said by the person they are impersonating. I could see _those_ jokes being called "tight fits."

Comment: Pardon my etymology, but could it be coarse slang?  A generalization of tight fit (sexual sense) = more pleasure/intensity?

Comment: If tight fit has ever meant "good joke," then it's on the Flapper end of that *Flappers 2 Rappers* scale. And Flappers in American youth culture date to the 1920s. My great-grandmother was a Flapper, so if it were that recent of a usage, someone here should be familiar with it. It sounds archaic and I find it odd that the author wouldn't cite his sources for that. Asking for the etymology of an idiom that hasn't been in use since the mid 19th century might be futile. The book suggests a chronicle from 1920 to present though.

Comment: @Sweet72 The slang dictionary of the 1850s suggested a tight fit is a good joke.

Comment: @J.R. I certainly like your rationale. I can understand how a tight fit could mean an especially appropriate joke. Naturally, I'm not quite sure of anything except for what I read in the book but I like your idea.

Comment: @JohnQPublic No, it's not. The title of the book may be _Flappers 2 Rappers_ but the oldest entries are from the 1850s. My great-grandmother was a flapper as well as yours and one of the oldest living flappers I'm sure of it. She'll be 106 years old in November. Not only was she a flapper but she was a New York City flapper of Italian descent from East Harlem. You can't be more hardboiled than that, old boy.

Comment: @User53019 Sir (or madam), I don't doubt you. That wasn't a critique; it was a suggestion. My point about the flappers of the 1920s is that most of us have a living relative who was alive at the same time as the Flapper generation, so someone should be aware of it. I couldn't find one single reference via Google, which I know doesn't count as research. Perhaps it's something that was either dying out with that generation or that simply never caught on. I had a tough-as-nails NYC great-grandma too, she never used that. My point is that I believe it's not in use and hasn't been for some time

Comment: @Sweet72: It's in A Collection of College Words and Customs (1851) by Benjamin Homer Hall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[A Collection of College Words and Customs](http://books.google.com/books?id=u1EXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA302&dq=%22tight+fit%22+joke&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MXRJUrHtGIj14QTH3IGQAw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA)* (1851) by Benjamin Homer Hall says:

> [image: TIGHT FIT. At the University of Vermont, a good joke is denominated by the students a tight fit, and the jokee is said to be " hard up."]

Answer (score 0):

"Tight fit" is not used in American English anymore.  The word "tight" (meaning cool) still comes and goes in younger slang but is definitely on a cool streak right now.